# Realm Android Sync operation with the database

Tags: realm

Does Realm Android support Sync operation with the database. We are actually looking to freeze on a Technology for storing the data in Local DB and further syncing with the Remote DB.

Answer (score 3):

Realm does not have any built-in sync as of now (October 2015). This is something [that is on our radar](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/913) (tracked on the cocoa project for historical reasons but applicable to all our libraries). In the meantime it’s relatively trivial to exchange data in & out of Realm via a REST API; our docs include quick examples of [how to access a REST API with Realm &  Retrofit](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#retrofit).

Answer (score 3):

This use-case is now allowed by the [Realm Mobile Platform and the Realm Object Server](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/).

The Realms are synchronized automatically and real-time, and have offline-caching functionality.

**EDIT:** Now in 2018-03-23, the pricing model is somewhat in a flux during the 2.x -> 3.x transition. Realm offers a Cloud platform, more details on their site. Either way, *that* syncs real-time between cloud ROS and the local db clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding 'isUpdatedOnServer' field in RealmModel and setting initial value as 'false'

you may perform sync like this. ("isUpdatedOnServer","false").findAll();, 
after successful response, you can update "isUpdatedOnServer" field to 'true'.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of the data being changed on the server, lets say after being synced from another phone. The first phone will not be updated.